# Formula field with ISPICKVAL

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to create a formula field. How do you combine ISPICKVAL from 2 different fields? Here is what I am trying and getting errors:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"A"), "100", 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"B"), "200", 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"C"), "300", 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"Fin") , "401", 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"Test") , "402", 
IF(ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"ABC") , "403", 
))))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please elaborate on what you mean by "getting errors:" Is it a syntax error in your formula? Do you get a non-specific error when you try to save a record? Do you get a specific error? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/367757/edit) your question to add that info - including *exact* text of any error. *(Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center and [take the Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).)*

Answer (score 1):

If you write your formula more like code - something like this...

```
IF(
   ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"A"), 
   "100", 
   IF(
      ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"B"), 
      "200", 
      IF(
         ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"C"), 
         "300", 
         IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"Fin") , 
            "401", 
            IF(
               ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"Test") , 
               "402", 
               IF(
                  ISPICKVAL(Business_Line__c,"D") && ISPICKVAL(Market__c ,"ABC") , 
                  "403", 
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

...you should be able to better quickly see that your last use of `IF` is wrong: you need three arguments and you only have two.

You need to add your *value_if_false*.